# Selecting multiple vertices by dragging box doesn't work

Tags: qgis-3, vertices, select

I'm doing a QGIS course at the moment using QGIS 3.10 on a Windows 10 Pro 64bit system at the moment.

Settings are default, except for the "filter invalid geometries" option is set to "ignore".

With a shape selected and editing+vertex tool active, I can select a single vertex (shift+click) and edit or delete it. I can also select all vertices on a line by pressing `shift+r` and then selecting the first and last vertex.

I cannot, however, select multiple vertices by dragging a box. I have tried for 2 hours now, and I just don't get why it doesn't work. Has anyone else seen this problem with QGIS 3.10, and has anyone solved it?

Comment: I have the exact same issue as OP describes. I have the layer selected, in edit mode, using the vertex tool, and when I click and drag a box over one or multiple vertices, nothing happens. It's as if I never clicked and dragged the box in the first place. I really hope there is a solution for this. I'm just adding this to let you know that there are more people who experience the same problem.

Comment: Did installing the newer stable version do the trick for you?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any issue with selecting multiple vertices by dragging a box to do selection. It works as expected:

[image]

I used the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button to delete the selected vertices.

Try after using `shift+r` or `shift+click` to click any place outside, at the white background, to remove the selection. Also press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button on your keyboard to remove any effects of the `shift+r` or `shift+click`. It may solve the problem.

Comment: Hello Ahmadhanb, this is how I would expect it to work. I reinstalled QGIS once more (I did that once before to no avail). **This time, I replaces QGIS 3.10.3-3 with version 3.10.4-1**. Vertex tool now works as shown in your video.
Thanks for your feedback, anyway.

Comment: @Moritz Glad the problem is solved. :)